# Border shows up only after toggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've a div styled using border, but it's not showing:

**DIV**

```
<div id="dvPrincipal" style="font-family:Verdana;
             display:inline; border:1px solid #000000;">
```

But after I fire a jquery method it shows up.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= chkExibeFiltros.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        $("#dvPrincipal").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

I really think, that's a browser issue (It must to works over IE), but I've no idea how to make it works.

Before runs Jquery Toggle event:

[image]

After runs Jquery Toggle event:

[image]

My JQuery runs in component click: "chkExibeFiltros", at Image "Mostrar Filtros"

Comment: Can you give a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it not working, as I created one using the HTML you provided and it is working fine.

Comment: It should work without Jquery. However, do you have an external CSS file linked to your page? Where the link tag is found? i.e after or before your div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.slideToggle()` will reset the `display` property to `inline-block`, thus enabling the border. Using `inline` on a `<div>` doesn't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `slideToggle()` this gives display property none and block not inline-block if you like to use `display:inline-block` property you have to do it like this

```
jQuery('selector').css('display','inline-block');
```